# how/why does rails decide to name some files with a plural or singular naming convention?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

When I run

```
rails generate scaffold HighScores
```

I get a migration that's named "high_scores", a model named "high_score", a view named "high_scores", and a controller named "high_scores" (inside which are both "@high_scores", "@high_score", and "HighScore")

Why such discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Model

By convention A Model is singular because it represents a single object like a Post, a User etc.. but database table names are plural because they represent a collection of objects.

In your case model name is `HighScore` and rails will look for class definition `class HighScore < ActiveRecord::Base` inside the file `high_score.rb`. You can perform all validations and model related task inside the class.

## Controller

A controller is plural because it represent model objects. Although using plural names for controllers is just a convention. For example Users controller will represent objects from User model.

In your case above scaffold will generate a controller `HighScores` and rails will look for class definition `class HighScoresController < ApplicationController` inside the file `high_scores_controller.rb`

In your controller you can find some restful actions such as `index`, `show`,`edit`, `update`, `destroy` . The purpose of index action is to list all highscores so you define a instance variable @highscores which will store all highscores from database table like  `@high_scores = HighScore.all`  which is then passed to the index view. Similarly the purpose of show action is to display a single highscore. In your show action you can define a instance variable  `@highscore` which will store a specific high score form db table like   `@high_score = HighScore.find(params[:id])`  and ten pass it to show view.

Answer (score 1):

For explaining your question I am taking one example like following:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

We are using singular name `User` instead of `Users` because name of the scaffold follows the convention of models, which are singular, rather than resources and controllers, which are plural.

I think this answer will helpful to you.